# Is there a way to do inverse z-transforms in Python?

Tags: python, inverse-transform

Is there a way to do inverse z-transforms in Python?  (I don’t see anything like this in NumPy or SciPy).

Comment: Made you an inverse-transform tag.

Comment: http://www.nehalemlabs.net/prototype/blog/2013/12/16/how-to-do-inverse-transformation-sampling-in-scipy-and-numpy/

Comment: Inverting a z-transform and inverting a cumulative distribution function (CDF) are unrelated problems.  (I have some experience with the latter problem because I used to teach a course on stochastic simulation at UCSB).

I have found a solution that works for my immediate problem: If the z-transform is a rational function, one can invert it calling `scipy.signal.lfilter` and passing it an impulse as input (this is an unadvertised application of that function).

Comment: https://github.com/garrettj403/CZT

Answer (score 1):

There is a great package called lcapy
https://pypi.org/project/lcapy/ .You can do a z transform or its inverse.

```
import lcapy as lc
from lcapy.discretetime import z

X0=z/(z-4)**2
xk=X0.IZT()
print(xk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy.signal.residuez for z^-n form of z-transform or scipy.signal.residue for z^n form of z-transform.

Answer (score 0):

The python control systems library https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/ provides this by via the impulse_response function as the impulse response is the inverse Z transform of the system transfer function in z.